# Looking for a function to change the font of Devc++ console to "Raster Character"

Tags: c, windows, windows-console

I need a function that can change the font of Devc++ to "Raster Character" beacause i need to stamp these ♥,♦,♠,♣  that have ASCII code:3,4,5,6.
Searching online i found this script(to which I added the stamp and the declaration of "a"),but not with character i need,or better if i write Raster in **wcscpy** as parameter inside the " ",does not display the desired character.How can i solve it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main (){
int a=3;
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX={0};
cf.cbSize=sizeof cf;
cf.dwFontSize.X=6;
cf.dwFontSize.Y=8;
wcscpy_s(cf.FaceName,L"console");
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),0,&cf);
printf("%c",a);
}
```

Comment: Hello! Please edit the question and copy/paste the relevant code *as text*.

Comment: The Microsoft documentation for console operations starts with [Consoles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/consoles).